# Error when try to access late-binding view in a cross-database query in Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

So far I've been able to do cross-database queries between two databases with data stored inside Redshift (using r3 node type). But when I do a query with a database that has an external schema/table from Redshift Spectrum. I got an error that the relations don't exist (my guess is that it is unreachable) and also I tried to do a late-binding view from the external schema/table and got the following error:

> ERROR: Localized temp table cannot be created while getting lbv
> definition

Creating instead a materialized view for the external table works, but we rather avoid it due to the operability maintenance of those views.

I want to do a cross-database query with data from Redshift Spectrum and Redshift.

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add an external table to a data share, even through a late binding view.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/considerations.html#limitations-datashare

`Amazon Redshift doesn't support adding external schemas, tables, or late-binding views on external tables to datashares.`

Answer (score 0):

If you are querying cross-database on the same cluster, the [documented limitations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/cross-database_usage.html#cross-database_limitation) of cross-database queries suggest defining the external schemas on each database.